Launch WPF app when clicking on a link in an email
I'm running a campaign to encourage users to use my WPF app. This campaign will send an email to the app's registered users with a link. When users click on that link, the WPF app should launch if the app is installed in their machine. Is it possible to achieve this?

Yes, it is. It depends on how the application is installed because you either need a reliable way to obtain the application path (e.g., from the Windows registry) or register your application as a default for a custom file type where you launch that (dummy) file to let Windows launch the associated application (your application). If there is not a real installation that registers the application, or the application is portable (then the location can change any time), you could register the application on the first start.

@BionicCode I published my WPF app using PublishSingleFile method. Then I created a simple installer with this exe using NSIS script. I want to send out the email to users who already have this app installed but are inactive for a long time (just to remind them the app is there and they can use it for free). So, in this case, how can I add a link to launch the app in the email content?

You can always register a custom URL protocol handler. Like mailto: would open a registered default application (and if none is registered asks to pick one) you can register your own URI scheme, for example myApp:.
The related registry key is very simple and structured as follows:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   myApp                                                       // Sub key
      (Default) = "MyApp URL launcher protocol"                  // Entry
      URL Protocol = ""                                          // Entry
      DefaultIcon                                                // Sub key
         (Default) = "myApp.exe,1"                                 // Entry
      shell                                                      // Sub key
         open                                                      // Sub key
            command                                                  // Sub key
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\myApp.exe" "%1"     // Entry


The following structure shows the minimal form of a new protocol handler key:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   myApp                                                       // Sub key
      URL Protocol = ""                                          // Entry
      shell                                                      // Sub key
         open                                                      // Sub key
            command                                                  // Sub key
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\myApp.exe" "%1"     // Entry


Note that you need elevated rights in order to manipulate the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key. Doing this from an installer that the user has elevated is the preferred way.
The following example uses C# sharp to create the new protocol mapping. However, you can use any script language of your choice. All you have to do is to create the new registry key.
string protocol = "myApp";
string myAppExecutablePath = "C:\myApp.exe";

using RegistryKey protocolSubkey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(protocol);
protocolSubkey.SetValue("URL Protocol", "");
using RegistryKey shellCommandKey = progIdSubkey.CreateSubKey(@"shell\open\command");
shellCommandKey.SetValue("", @$"""{myAppExecutablePath}"" ""%1""");

You then use it e.g.
<a href="myApp:">Start My App</a>

You can also pass arguments to your application
<a href="myApp:This is a message">Start My App</a>

Or simply enter myApp: into the address bar of a web browser.
Or use Process.Start.
Then in your WPF application use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs to extract the args

// Retruns "myApp:This is a message"
string argument = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];

// Returns "This is a message"
string message = argument.Split(':')[1];

It must be said that it is not safe to process any arguments as it's easy to inject malicious code simply by modifying the actual URI.
You can find more information at Microsoft learn: Registering an Application to a URI Scheme

No. At least not if you mean external users whose Windows installations you can't alter.
You probably want to include instructions on how to install and open the app in the e-mail anyway. Including links to executable applications in e-mails is a bad practice. Clicking on such links, as a receiver, is a huge security risk that should always be avoided.
